# Деепричастный оборот с инфинитивом

Tags: грамотная-речь

В данном случае деепричастный оборот выступает как добавочное действие к инфинитиву "умереть" или же к глаголу "пишу"?
Цитата: "Я пишу в своей тетради о том, как хочется умереть, вонзив в сердце нож".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здравый смысл подсказывает, что трудно писать, уже вонзив нож в сердце.

Это грамматически допустимое предложение ([справочник Розенталя](http://rosental-book.ru/styli_xlviii.html#sect212.1)):

> В ряде случаев возможно употребление деепричастного оборота, не
>   выражающего действие подлежащего <...>: в безличном предложении при
>   инфинитиве, например: *Приходилось работать в трудных условиях, не имея в течение многих недель ни одного свободного дня для отдыха.*

Ещё можно добавить, что разумно составлять предложения так, чтобы деепричастие (подобно местоимениям) было ближе всего к дополняемому глаголу.